# how to tell which image of a set was tapped on in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

For one of my tableview, there are images in some of cells and there could be more than one images in each of those cells. Now when user tapped on an image, I want to bring up a image viewer to show the full image. But I have a hard time to figure out the best way to know which picture was tapped on. I created them as UIImageView. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set tag for imageview and you can easily find out the tapped image

Comment: This will not work only by setting tag. you have to think about what will be tag. In case , if row 1 has 3 images and row 2 has 2 images then what are images tag?

Answer (score 3):

Set tag for each images of cell.

In .h declare

```
 NSInteger TagValue ;
```

In .m ViewDidLoad

```
 TagValue = 0;
```

At CellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
TagValue++;

image1.tag = TagValue;

TagValue++;

image2.tag = TagValue;
```

On selection of it , now you have tag value on that you can get particular selected image.

And to get images form array

```
image1.image = [array objectAtIndex:image1.tag];
```

you will get your respective image.

Answer (score 0):

set the tag of each image of a particular cell and then you can access those images through their tags

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is , instead of using UIImageView , use Costume Button and set  the Image of That costume button and give all the buttons different tags... each cell will have set of buttons with different tags and by assigning the single  selector to all button you can easily determine that which image is clicked.

or

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags as suggested in the other answers or you can use switch case

in the method -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switch(indexPath.section) {

    case 0:{
//set the _imagename = @"Something"
break;
}
    case 1:{
//set the _imagename = @"Something else"
break;
}
}
```

hope this helps